# Android Studio - Navigation between activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I may be doing a very dumb mistake somewhere, and this question may seem really silly, but, i can't figure out the reason why this is happening.

I have a HomeActivity with an ImageView and when I click on it, i need to go to a DummyActivity(created for purpose of testing). The DummyActivity has a textview with text, "this is a dummy page". But, the screen just doesn't display anything.

I am a newbie with Android Studio, but, i guess it doesn't relate to it.

Here is my code:

ImageView onClick in HomeActivity:

```
 mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_1);
 mImageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("HomeActivity", "ImageView 1 Clicked");
            //startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DummyActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

DummyActivity onCreate():

```
public class DummyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);
}
}
```

activity_dummy.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a dummy page"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".DummyActivity"
        android:label="DummyActivity"></activity>
```

The logcat displays, "ImageView 1 Clicked", but nothing after that. No errors, nothing. What am i doing wrong here?

Update: Changed backgroundColor for LinearLayout and textColor for the TextView, but the changes are not reflecting. The preview in Android Studio is showing the layout just fine, but, the screen on device is just blank as before, with black background.

[image][image]

Not sure why?

Comment: What do you mean nothing after that? a blank screen? or the screen not changing at all?

Comment: The screen changes, but its blank.

Comment: I think that the color of the text is white as well the background color.
try adding android:textColor="#000" on the TextView.

Comment: I tested that.. i changed the background of linearlayout to white and textview color to black, but nothing is displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overriden wrong `onCreate()` method. Use this one instead:

```
public class DummyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to change the activity?

In my App i use only one Activity but multiple fragments (see [Dialogfragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)). My Activty acts like a manager class for all other fragments and fragment transitions.

In your case i would create an "homeFragment" and add button callbacks like

```
private void buttonSwitchToDummy()
{
    HomeActivity act = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
    act.replaceFragment(act.mDummyFragment);
}
```

Adding this to HomeActivity

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean deleteBackStack)
{
    if(fragment==null)
        return;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(deleteBackStack)
    {   
        // deletes the complete backstack and set fragment
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: My concern is not about Activity or Fragment, i wish to know what is that i am doing wrong.